# INSERT INTO SELECT JOIN returning null from joined table (Postgres)

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

I'm using the following Knex statement to copy data from two tables into another table:

```js
const insert = knex.from(knex.raw('?? (??, ??, ??, ??, ??, ??, ??)', ['carrier', 'docket_number', 'dot_number', 'legal_name', 'dba_name', 'nbr_power_unit', 'rating', 'carrier_operation']))
        .insert(knex('carrier_temp as ct').leftJoin('carrier_census_temp as cen', 'ct.dot_number', 'cen.DOT_NUMBER')
            .select(['ct.docket_number as docket_number',
                'ct.dot_number as dot_number',
                'ct.legal_name as legal_name',
                'ct.dba_name as dba_name',
                'cen.tot_pwr as nbr_power_unit',
                'cen.RATING as rating',
                knex.raw('CASE WHEN cen.crrinter = \'A\' THEN \'INTERSTATE\' ELSE \'INTRASTATE\' END as "carrier_operation"')])).toString()
const conflict = knex.raw('ON CONFLICT (docket_number) DO NOTHING;').toString()
const q = insert + conflict
await knex.raw(q).debug()
```

The generated sql is:

```sql
INSERT INTO "carrier" 
            ( 
                        "docket_number", 
                        "dot_number", 
                        "legal_name", 
                        "dba_name", 
                        "nbr_power_unit", 
                        "rating", 
                        "carrier_operation" 
            ) 
SELECT    "ct"."docket_number" AS "docket_number", 
          "ct"."dot_number"    AS "dot_number", 
          "ct"."legal_name"    AS "legal_name", 
          "ct"."dba_name"      AS "dba_name", 
          "cen"."tot_pwr"      AS "nbr_power_unit", 
          "cen"."RATING"       AS "rating", 
          CASE 
                    WHEN cen.crrinter = 'A' THEN 'INTERSTATE' 
                    ELSE 'INTRASTATE' 
          END                   AS "carrier_operation" 
FROM      "carrier_temp"        AS "ct" 
left join "carrier_census_temp" AS "cen" 
ON        "ct"."dot_number" = "cen"."DOT_NUMBER" ON conflict (docket_number) DO nothing;
```

The `carrier` table receives all the columns that are referenced from `carrier_temp` or `ct` correctly, but the columns pulled from `carrier_census_temp` or `cen` are all ending up as `NULL` (nbr_power_unit, rating, and carrier_operation). That is, except for the case statement, which is setting every row's carrier_operation to `INTRASTATE`. If I instead equate NULL in the case statement, it still sets every row to `INTRASTATE`. Does anyone have any idea why this is?

Comment: Do you have any sample data. From what you have written, it looks like the dot_number in both ct and cen might be different.

Comment: @VarunT Oops you're totally right. Turns out a 0 somehow got appended to the front of every dot_number on the census table such that there was never anything joined. Wow thank you for breaking my stupor on that one...

Comment: No worries. Looks like you should consider integer data types for dot_number instead of characters.

Answer (score 0):

See comments on question. I totally missed something wrong in my data that led to nothing ever being joined, which just leads everything to always be NULL.